# Prove that $I_n=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{2n}(t)\, dt$ is convergent to $0$

Tags: calculus

We have 
$$I_n=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{2n}(t)\, dt$$ 
and we need to show that it is convergent to $0$.

Comment: what is the condition about $g$?

Comment: My guess is $\tan^{2n}t$

Comment: Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have, by replacing $t$ with $\arctan x$:
$$0\color{red}{\leq}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\tan^{2n}(t)\,dt = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^2}\,dx\color{red}{\leq}\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\,dx=\frac{1}{2n+1}.$$

Comment: You make it to seems so simple